# Apache does not Compress/Deflate/GZIP responses

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have set up apache .htaccess file so that it should compress JSONs that my application spews. The application is written in python, and is linked to apache with CGI scripts.

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/json application/json
</ifmodule>
```

My JSONs returned are still not GZipped, although static files returned are. Are there ideas or thoughts as to how I can fix this?

I am using Apache2

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess doesn't affect script output, so you will have to handle gzip compression from Python app. E.g. in case of Django app you can use GZipMiddleware.